# The recent files area is always empty

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-word-2007

I installed `Microsoft Office Enterprise 2007`. When I use `Word 2007` , opening a word document, closing it, exiting Word, reopening Word then the recent files area is empty !
The system is `Windows XP Pro SP3`.
How to make opened files listed in the recent files area ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be the the show recent file settings is not set!
check here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/word-help/customize-the-list-of-recently-used-files-HA010075984.aspx